# Benefit of using Infura for deploying smart contract

Tags: infura

I have gone through Infura's website, blog and other resources but I am not clear about the benefit I'll get from using it for and after deploying my smart contract for an ICO sale. Do I really need it? Frankly, most of the things are going above my head. Can somebody explain it to me in simple terms?

Answer (score 3):

Infura has the advantage that you do not have to setup your own node.

The disadvantage is that you have to trust infura.

> Frankly, most of the things are going above my head.

This is not a desirable condition if you're planing to do an ICO.

Comment: But, you dont need to run your own node to deploy a smart contract. You can just use any public node if you have the rpc url. Still not clear whats the benefit.

Answer (score 1):

it is easy to use API and developer tools provide secure, reliable, and scalable access to Ethereum and IPFS.the advantage will be that you don't have to set up your own node and download data and sync up.

And people are using infura as there site suggests that 10B+ requests per day and 35,000+ dapps are served till now.All the best for your ICO.